# What is the origin of the prefix "Mords-"?

Tags: etymology, colloquial, prefix

In colloquial German we hear sayings like:

> Ich habe einen Mordshunger und muß erstmal was essen.
>   Wir haben auf unserere Reise mordsviel gesehen.
>   Dieser Mordstyp macht einfach geile Musik.

Where does this prefix "*Mords-*" come from? Is it in any way related to "*Mord"* (i.e. *murder*)?

Comment: Interestingly, the question is in English but both answers are in German.

Comment: This reminds me of the expression "she is dressed to kill", meaning elegant, sexy,...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Aus dem Grimm:

> 11) mord *in zusammensetzungen, als schelte für etwas äuszerst böses oder schlimmes, vergl.* mordmähre, mordracker, mordschlag 2; *sodann in verstärkungen, selbst derb lobenden, der volksmäszigen sprache, vgl.* mordbrav, mordkerl, mordmäszig *u. a., an den begriff des frevelhaften anknüpfend, wie ähnlich* sündlich, verflucht *gebraucht werden, vergl. auch* meineidig *oben sp. 1923 fg., und* keibe *th. 5, 432,* luder *oben sp. 1233 in zusammensetzungen. mundartlich erscheint so auch* mords-, *man hört* ein mordskerl, mordsmäszig saufen können, mordsviel geld, ein mordsweg, *u. a.*

Wie viele andere Wörter wird dies auch übertragen gebraucht, zunächst für etwas äußerst böses oder schlimmes (also nicht notwendigerweise mit Mord zusammenhängend) und später dann auch in positiven Verstärkungen, ähnlich wie bei "verflucht". Umgangssprachlich ist dann das Präfix "Mords-" daraus geworden, das auch heute noch gebräuchlich ist.

Answer (score 4):

[Wiktionary sagt](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Mords-), die Vorsilbe stamme von "mordsmäßig". Das wiederum setzt sich zusammen aus "Mord", einem [Fugenelement](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fugenelement) und "-mäßig".